# communication between the website and C# winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, communication

We have a Website (hosted somewhere) and C# Application (which is installed on my PC). I need to accomplish the following:

1. Customers fill up the form on the website, i.e. the task is "created"
2. C# Application immediately receives this data from the website and process it
3. The result is sent back to the server, i.e. "task accomplished" message
4. The website updates status regarding this task

How do you build this kind of link between the website and an app?

In the past I've used TCPListener to communicate between two C# apps. I'm also familiar with the UDPlistener and such.. Will this knowledge be of some use? The website is going to be build on the PHP.

Some tips and advises are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why dont you try `HTTPWebRequest` and `HTTPWebResponse`

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it! I just don't know where to start and what to google..

Comment: @akhil these methods are used as if I just typed exact URL into the address bar.. so, theoretically, anyone with correct URL will be able to "get the output". Is that so? My main concern here - is this method secure to use? P.S.: I'm planning to send POST messages every minute or two..

Comment: I've managed to get WebRequest/WebResponse method working.. but the response time if very slow.. 10-15 seconds at first launch, else up to 2 seconds..

Comment: proxy was the problem.. now the problem is solved and communications link is built

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website should not be dependant on an application running on your home or office PC, so the site should publish some kind of service or feed. You can make this a webservice, which is quite easy in PHP.

You then consume this service from your C# application. Make it request the new tasks regularly, by polling the service. When you've received new tasks you process them in your application, and when you've done what you want to do you update the tasks on your server using another webservice call.

All this can be done using some sort of queue in the database that backs your website.

Comment: As far as I understand - this PHP service requires SOAP in order to be run.. Is this so called SOAP supported by most of the hosting providers? Also, I've googled a lot, and it seems like there are few more possible solutions to my problem. For example "Web Sockets", that can be implemented using C# "alchemy websockets" or "websocket4net" packages.. Both require .NET framework on server. Are these options viable? I've heard that servers with .NET support are expensive. How would you compare your solution to "HTTPWebRequest and HTTPWebResponse" approach? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the C# application a  web service may be a windows host depending on your requirement

you can the webservice from php as shown here [Using PHP to call a WCF web service with multiple bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188663/using-php-to-call-a-wcf-web-service-with-multiple-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the control over your web host and your client, you could try setting up a WCF service with duplex contracts which allows the server to callback your client. Your PHP site can call the WCF service and it can in turn notify the client. Else you will have to go with the polling method where the Desktop client has to poll the web service to get the list of pending tasks.