# Help me convert this PHP SOAP code to C#

Tags: c#, php, soap

I am trying to do some C# SOAP calls and can't seem to get any good examples on how to do it.  I read an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027745/having-trouble-getting-my-head-around-soap-in-php) of mine about a SOAP call in PHP and thought maybe asking you guys to rewrite it in C# would be a good place to start.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.hotelscombined.com/api/LiveRates.asmx?WSDL');

$client->__soapCall('HotelSearch', 
    array(
        array('request' => 
            array(
                'ApiKey' => 'THE_API_KEY_GOES_HERE', // note that in the actual code I put the API key in...
                'UserID' => session_id(),
                'UserAgent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                'UserIPAddress' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'HotelID' => '50563',
                'Checkin' => '07/02/2009',
                'Checkout' => '07/03/2009',
                'Guests' => '2',
                'Rooms' => '1',
                'LanguageCode' => 'en',
                'DisplayCurrency' => 'usd',
                'TimeOutInSeconds' => '90'
            ) 
        ) 
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4):

First step would be to create a proxy. Use the [Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) dialog box in Visual Studio and provide the WSDL address: `http://www.hotelscombined.com/api/LiveRates.asmx?WSDL`.

Second step is to call the service:

```
using (var client = new LiveRatesSoapClient())
{
    var response = client.HotelSearch(new HotelSearchRequest
    {
        ApiKey = "THE_API_KEY_GOES_HERE",
        Checkin = new DateTime(2009, 7, 2),
        Checkout = new DateTime(2009, 7, 3),
        DisplayCurrency = "usd",
        Guests = 2,
        HotelID = 50563,
        LanguageCode = "en",
        Rooms = 1,
        TimeOutInSeconds = 90,
        UserAgent = "???",
        UserID = "???",
        UserIPAddress = "???"
    });
}
```

Note that depending on the WSDL some property names might be different than the ones I provided in my sample as I don't know the WSDL but Intellisense should help you.

There's a nice [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) you might read.

Comment: @Darin - Thanks this was a great step one for me.  I am having trouble though with your line one particularly the `LiveRatesSoapClient()` class, should it just automatically be there after I add the service reference?  Because VS doesn't seem to know what I'm talking about

Comment: You need to add the correct using. Place cursor over the `LiveRatesSoapClient` class, you should see a small red box at the bottom right corner of the word and then either click on it or Shift + Alt + F10 and import the correct using directive. I would recommend you reading some beginner tutorial on .NET in general before trying more advanced stuff.