# Calling PHP Web Services in C#

Tags: php, asp.net, service

I want to convert following PHP code to C#.

```
$client=new SOAPClient(API_URL."www/ws_rpc.php?wsdl&actor=fieldreport_actions&client=".API_KEY,array("uri"=>"SOME_URL","style"=>SOAP_RPC,"use"=>SOAP_ENCODED,"encoding"=>"UTF-8"));
$auth = $client->is_valid_panelist_login("login_type_email",$username,$password);
```

How can I do it? I found 1 sample at: [Help me convert this PHP SOAP code to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547188) But this looks bit different.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to generate a proxy class from the WSDL. This could be done directly in Visual Studio by clicking on the [`Add Service Reference...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) and pointing to the WSDL. Once you have the proxy you could directly call the method. It could look something like this:

```
using (var proxy = new WebServiceClient())
{
    var auth = proxy.is_valid_panelist_login("login_type_email", "user", "pwd");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. 
Actually, I did it. But I get "The request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation Failed" error. Don't know, what's going wrong over here. :(

Comment: This exception could occur if the web service sends unsupported headers or doesn't respect the SOAP specification.

Comment: Worked. Need to set  System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; before calling any web method. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94235/The-request-failed-with-HTTP-status-417-Expectatio.aspx