# How to set this SOAP header in PHP

Tags: php, soap, header

I try to set SOAP header like this:

```
<tns:Authentication xmlns:tns="iSklep3">
    <ApiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">abc</ApiKey>
</tns:Authentication>
```

I make it this way:

```
//...
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlServer);
    $headerBody = array("ApiKey" => "abc");
    $header = new SoapHeader("iSklep3", "Authentication", $headerBody);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
//...
//calling soap methods
...
```

When I call methods, it returns Api key is wrong, but it should be right. Knows somebody where the problem of SOAP header can be?

Comment: Any way we can take a look at the class you're calling?

Comment: $res = $client->getProductAvailableQuantity($params);
it returns Api key is wrong, but api key should be right

Comment: or what do you mean? This is how service looks http://services.w3.org/xslt?xslfile=http://tomi.vanek.sk/xml/wsdl-viewer.xsl&xmlfile=http://orderapi.beta.i-sklep.pl/soap/order?wsdl&transform=Submit#op.d1e540

Comment: It seems you're missing another method to be called in that class. Look at your answers.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question for better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the call function after setting the header.

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                     'uri'      => "http://test-uri/"));
$header = new SoapHeader('http://soapinterop.org/echoheader/', 
                            'echoMeStringRequest',
                            'hello world');

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$client->__soapCall("echoVoid", null);
?>
```

Source: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php

Comment: Should have mentioned it before. You also need to send an ApiKey in __soapCall
There's an example in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027745/having-trouble-getting-my-head-around-soap-in-php